# How to make multiple matches?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Transactions list:

Column A has IDs (They repeat as one ID can do many row entries based on events)

Column B has Flags (thing1 or thing2 or thing3)

Column C has Cleared list of ids with no duplicates

**Column D: How do I match C1 and return how many times that id is listed in Column A with "thing1" being its flag in Column B.**

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(A:A,C1,B:B,"thing1")`

Comment: Post it as an answer. I never really knew how to do it...